# Video player and Media Player don't work in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

The built-in Video Player and Windows Media Player do not play any videos in Windows. I have tried in many formats. Is there a solution?

Comment: are you trying to play a DVD format?

Comment: .avi format. I also tried .mpeg

Comment: Note, the file extension is the format of the container, not the format of the underlying video. Maybe you are missing some codecs. Try using the [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/), which in my experience, has much better codec support.

Answer (score 4):

AVI is just a container and can contain pretty much any codec. You likely don't have the codec installed to play the file. [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) is a handy application for finding out what codec lurks within an AVI file. Also there are things like the [Combined COmmunity Codec Pack](http://cccp-project.net/) which are a comprehensive package of most codecs people might need nowadays.

.mpeg files are probably MPEG-2, I guess. Support for that (along with DVD playback) was removed from Windows 8 since almost all customers never play a DVD on their Windows computer, so raising the price to include the MPEG-2 licensing costs for everyone is actually pretty stupid.

[VLC](http://videolan.org) should play pretty much anything you throw at it, though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Windows 8. In my case, the problem is the new [ATI Mobility Radeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon#R600) 5650 Windows 8 driver. Everything related with graphics card look OK, but when you try to play a video, is is not shown. The problem comes from the video hardware acceleration, and it seems to be an error of the new Windows 8 drivers.

My solution was to install my old Windows 7 driver (provided by Sony; I have a Sony Vaio). Graphics performance is worse, but at least I can play any video.

Comment: Just use a different video player and disable hardware-acceleration in it.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing some codecs. Windows Media Player cannot play videos if the codec used to encode it is missing.

Windows Media Player in Windows 8 has [dropped DVD support](http://www.theverge.com/2012/5/4/2998106/windows-8-drops-dvd-playback-media-center-upgrade), to save on licensing costs.

To play the files, you can:

- use the [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/), which is the easiest solution
- download codecs so that Windows Media Player can play more formats, for example:

  - [Xvid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvid), a GPL library for MPEG-4, includes encoding
  - [Combined Community Codec Pack](http://cccp-project.net/), support for more codecs, but only for decoding (no problem if you only watch videos, and don't intend to save anything in the format)

Comment: One can also download the Media Center add-on ( for free until Jan 2013 ) although that doesn't include all codecs either.